# A participle phrase

Tags: grammar

I am an English instructor with a vast experience. But I am confused about a grammar point. I fail to understand whether a participle non-finite clause is a part of the subject or predicate, in other words it modfies the subject word or the predicate word that is the verb itself.

For example:

> The dog, seizing the man by the collar, dragged him out.

Is the clause seizing the man by the collar, a part of the subject or the predicate. Does it modify the noun *dog* or the verb *dragged*?

Similarly,

> Flying into the storm, he risked his life and limb.

Comment: Neither. The gerund-participial clause "seizing the man by the collar" is a supplementary adjunct (here, a parenthetical) , Supplements are not modifiers but loosely attached expressions set off by intonation (and usually by punctuation) presenting supplementary, non-integrated content. Supplements are usually adjuncts, which is the case in your example. The same applies to your other example.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, "seizing the man by the collar" is a free modifier, (also known as a sentence adverb) that modifies the whole  of the main clause, which is "The dog dragged him out."

Comment: @user81561 The whole point about supplements is that they are not modifiers. And, of course, "seizing the man by the collar" is not an adverb but a clause. Adverbs are single words like "very", "clearly", "almost" etc.

Comment: The whole point about free modifiers is that they influence the main verb clause and therefore that which modifies it is adverbial.

Comment: @user81561  Supplements have an 'anchor' to which they relate. Here, the anchor is not the verb but the subject "the dog". Importantly, it is the lack of integration into the syntactic structure that distinguishes it from a dependency construction, thus ruling it out as being a modifier.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *The dog,* [*seizing the man by the collar*], *dragged him out.*
>
> [2] [*Flying into the storm*], *he risked his life and limb*.

Neither. The bracketed gerund-participial clauses are best analysed as supplementary adjuncts (here, parentheticals).

Supplements are not modifiers but loosely attached expressions set off by intonation (and usually by punctuation) presenting supplementary, non-integrated content. They are usually adjuncts, which is the case in your examples.

In neither example is there any explicit indication of the semantic relation between the supplement and the anchor. This has to be inferred from the content of the clause and/or the context. The natural interpretation of [2], for example, is temporal: "when he flew into the storm".